# Social network graph using a javascript library

Tags: javascript, graph, social-networking

I intend to draw a directed graph (node-oriented). The nodes in the graph are dynamically generated. I am wondering if there's any good js library out there that solves my problem. Edges and weights need to be custom  configured.

Thanks,
Deepak.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [JavaScript InfoVis Toolkit](http://thejit.org/) provides graph view that can be dynamically generated and updated using AJAX etc. It provides a number of views that are customizable.

Answer (score 4):

From my experience D3.js is most flexible

d3js.org

also there is new sigmajs libaray

http://sigmajs.org/

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked into the [RaphaelJS library](http://raphaeljs.com/)?

Check out the awesome demos on the site.  It's cross-browser, because it uses VML in IE and SVG in other browsers.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [arborjs.org](http://arborjs.org) too.

Answer (score 2):

Commercially licensed - [KeyLines](http://key-lines.com) would do the job - also cross-browser, both old IE & newer browsers supported (incl iPads).  Disclaimer: I help to develop it ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Cytoscape Web JS will do what you need.

Check out the github repository here http://cytoscape.github.com/cytoscape.js/
and you can play around with some demos here http://cytoscape.github.com/cytoscapeweb/